# Is it possible to develop a custom keyboard for iOS using react-native?

Tags: ios, keyboard, react-native

I want to develop a custom keyboard for iOS and android using react-native. Is it possible to do this. If possible please could you help me out with a few suggestions. I tried looking up the UIInputViewController on react-native but wasn't able to find it. 
By custom keyboard I meant, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html. 
You might have heard of swype and emoji keyboards. Thats what I meant by a custom keyboard.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you remove the hold ?

Comment: Can you guys unblock this question. I have edited this. If you guys can't monitor the edited questions, you shouldn't be blocking it in the first place.

Comment: Check out this blog post. Hopefully it'll send you in the correct direction until the SO mods realize this is a beneficial question... https://medium.com/rendez-voo/messages-app-app-extension-ios10-with-react-native-6d22ece64598#.q784nwcfb

Comment: This is a valid question so I'm surprised it was closed. It's not "too broad", it's about a specific thing: custom keyboards.
Not sure if this is custom enough -- https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-custom-keyboard

Comment: Someone posted a video showing custom keyboard in RN, but no code shared. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YV3p09KoYKw

Comment: Voting for reopen, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @barryjones, I voted to reopen the question but it is unlikely that an old question will get enough votes to be reopened. I don't know how it is too broad - it is very specific about a topic so narrow that it's hard to find any info on the web so it is a perfect topic for a question here. I suggest that you write a new question about it and I will give it a bounty to attract answers because I would like to know exactly what you're asking about. Thanks.

Comment: The answer to the question, by the way, is no. Keyboards, like other extensions in iOS, are limited by memory. Merely loading JavaScriptCore and some of the nonsense RN loads, you run out of memory. In the simulator, the OS does not limit the memory usage, but that is misleading. Once you run on a real device, you hit the memory issue.